# R: multiply rows of matrices

Tags: r, matrix

I have two matrices

```
B <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12, 13, 14, 15), nrow = 3, ncol = 5)
C <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12, 13, 14, 15), nrow = 3, ncol = 5)
```

I want to calculate crossprod of rows of those matrices. Currently I am doing it this way:

```
S = numeric(3)
for(i in 1:3){
  S[i]= B[i,] %*% C[i,]     #crossprod(B[i,], C[i,])
}
```

or this way

```
apply(B*C, 1, sum)
```

Neither of them is fast. Is there an idiomatic way to do that faster?

In the end, I want to improve the following piece of code

```
beta_numerator <- matrix(0,K,V)
for(k in (1:K)){
  for(i in (1:V)){
    beta_numerator[k,i] <- crossprod(m_tf[i,], gamma[i,,k])
  }
}
```

I changed it to

```
beta_numerator <- matrix(0,K,V)
for(k in (1:K)){
  beta_numerator[k,] <- apply(m_tf * gamma[,,k], c(1), sum)
}
```

It is a little bit faster, but not very spectacular. Can anybody help?

Comment: `rowSums(B*C)` will be a faster version of `apply(B*C, 1, sum)`]. Looks to be between 3 and 4 times faster.

Comment: [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36585217/calculating-column-wise-dot-product-between-two-matrices), but multiplying columns - Gregors suggestion is a good one

Answer (score 0):

Gregor's rowSums-solution will be the fastet. However, if you byte-code compile your for-loop (will not work equally well for apply), you will get similar speed - and it is not much effort:

```
B <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12, 13, 14, 15), nrow = 3, ncol = 5)
C <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12, 13, 14, 15), nrow = 3, ncol = 5)

# I want to calculate crossprod of rows of those matrices. Currently I am doing it this way:
for.fun <- function (B, C) {
  res <- numeric(nrow(B))
  for (i in seq_along(res)) {
    res[i] <- B[i, ] %*% C[i, ]
  }
  res
}
for.fun.compiled <- compiler::cmpfun(for.fun)

# or this way
apply.fun <- function(B, C) {
  apply(B*C, 1, sum) 
}
apply.fun.compiled <- compiler::cmpfun(apply.fun)

# rowSums
row.fun <- function(B, C) {
  rowSums(B * C)
}
row.fun.compiled <- compiler::cmpfun(row.fun)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  apply.fun (B, C),
  apply.fun.compiled (B, C),
  for.fun(B, C),
  for.fun.compiled (B, C),
  row.fun(B, C),
  row.fun.compiled(B, C)
)

# result:   
# Unit: microseconds
#                     expr    min     lq     mean  median      uq      max neval cld
#           apply.fun(B, C) 20.081 20.528 40.24717 20.9740 21.4200 1758.209   100   a
# apply.fun.compiled(B, C) 19.635 20.528 21.95117 20.9735 21.4200   39.270   100   a
#            for.fun(B, C)  4.909  5.801 45.02650  6.2480  6.6940 3880.108   100   a
#   for.fun.compiled(B, C)  4.909  5.801  6.66713  6.2475  6.6935   19.189   100   a
#            row.fun(B, C)  4.016  4.909 19.55925  5.8010  5.8020 1391.395   100   a
#   row.fun.compiled(B, C)  4.016  4.463  5.51139  5.3550  5.8020   17.850   100   a
```